# how to save from data from session to the database?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2005, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently using rails 3 app. How am I supposed to save data from session to the database?

Here's my controller:

```
def step2
    @cart = current_cart

    checkin = params[:checkin]
    checkout = params[:checkout]
    @amenities = Amenity.available(checkin, checkout)

    session[:checkin] = checkin
    session[:checkout] = checkout
end
```

and my view:

```
<%= form_for(@transaction, :validate => true) do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :Transaction_Date, :value => Time.now %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rsv_type, :value => "Online" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :rsv_status, :value => "Pending" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :checkin, :value => session[:checkin] %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :checkout, :value => session[:checkout] %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am not very clear about your question.

If you want to fetch some data from session, then save it into database, just like what you wrote:

```
someEntity.create(:checkin => session[:checkin])
```

And if you want to store the session in database , you should  config your rails application:

```
#edit your config/initializers/session_store.rb  
YourAppName::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```